# in ssis, how to find latest folder by timestamp

Tags: ssis, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have File System Task in my package which copy a folder from source location to destination. At destination, if that folder doesn't exist, it's newly created.

I want SSIS to pick latest folder (using time-stamp) from directory as source and create new folder with same name at destination via File System Task.

Example: I have `D:\Folder 1\SourceFolder` copy to  `G:\Folder 1\SourceFolder`.

Can somebody help me to figure out.

Comment: I'm lost, why you have oracle-sqldeveloper as a "tag" ?

Comment: In tag it says Oracle-SQLDeveloper. That's why I tag on it.

Comment: Removed bold text, fixed markup, grammar.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me in this?